# How to draw ROC curve for a multi-class dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, roc, multiclass-classification

I have a multi-class confusion matrix as below and would like to draw its associated ROC curve for one of its classes (e.g. class 1). I know the "one-VS-all others" theory should be used in this case, but I want to know how exactly we need to change the threshold to obtain different pairs of TP and corresponding FP rates.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT6qg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SkLearn has a handy implementation which calculates the tpr and fpr and another function which generates the auc for you. You can just apply this to your data by treating each class on its own (all other data being negative) by looping through each class. The code below was inspired by [the scikit-learn page on this topic itself](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html).

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

#generating synthetic data
N_classes = 3
N_per_class=100
labels = np.concatenate([[i]*N_per_class for i in range(N_classes)])
preds = np.stack([np.random.uniform(0,1,N_per_class*N_classes) for _ in range(N_classes)]).T
preds /= preds.sum(1,keepdims=True) #approximate softmax

tpr,fpr,roc_auc = ([[]]*N_classes for _ in range(3))
f,ax = plt.subplots()
#generate ROC data
for i in range(N_classes):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(labels==i, preds[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
    ax.plot(fpr[i],tpr[i])
plt.legend(['Class {:d}'.format(d) for d in range(N_classes)])
plt.xlabel('FPR')
plt.ylabel('TPR')
```

[image: And the output...]